# Executing Method Call - C#

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering if there is a better way of executing multiple methods depending on a value?

I have a Property that gets the NumberOflegs. NumberOfLegs can have a value between 1-6. If the value is 1, it needs to execute InsertLeg1Details. If the value is 2, it needs to execute InsertLeg1Details and InsertLeg2Details, etc.

```
  private void SaveLegs()
    {
        switch (NumberOfLegs)
        {
            case 1:
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg1Details());
                break;
            case 2:
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg1Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg2Details());
                break;
            case 3:
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg1Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg2Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg3Details());
                break;
            case 4:
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg1Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg2Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg3Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg4Details());
                break;
            case 5:
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg1Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg2Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg3Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg4Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg5Details());
                break;
            case 6:
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg1Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg2Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg3Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg4Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg5Details());
                SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg6Details());
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sounds like a perfect opportunity to combine a lazy generator with Linq's [Take()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-6.0) method

Answer (score 3):

With reflection you can do something like this

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
for(int i = 1; i <= NumberOfLegs; i++)
{
  string toBeCalledMethodName = $"InsertLeg{i}Details";
  MethodInfo toBeCalledMethod = thisType.GetMethod(toBeCalledMethodName);

  var details = (FlightDetails)toBeCalledMethod.Invoke(this);
  SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(details);
}
```

I assumed your `InsertLegXYZ` methods are returning `FlightDetails` instances based on [your previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276135/saving-multiple-lists-to-database-c-forms).

Answer (score 2):

You should strive to avoid repeating operations like that.

My suggestion would be to test at each stage whether there's more work to do.  If we've finished, then return.

```
private void SaveLegs()
{
    if (NumberOfLegs < 1 || NumberOfLegs > 6) { return; }

    SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg1Details());
    if (NumberOfLegs == 1) { return; }

    SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg2Details());
    if (NumberOfLegs == 2) { return; }

    SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg3Details());
    if (NumberOfLegs == 3) { return; }

    SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg4Details());
    if (NumberOfLegs == 4) { return; }

    SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg5Details());
    if (NumberOfLegs == 5) { return; }

    SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg6Details());
}
```

Assuming you have control over the functions, consider replacing (or augmenting) them with a single function that takes a leg number as argument - the code then becomes a simple loop:

```
private void SaveLegs()
{
    for (int i = 1;  i <= NumberOfLegs;  ++i) {
        SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLegDetails(i));
    }
}
```

Here, I've assumed that `InsertLegDetails()` will respond appropriately (e.g. throw an exception) if its argument is too high - the original action of just ignoring all the data seems a poor choice to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why are there `InsertLeg<N>Details()`s in the first place?

Alternative *assuming order of execution insignificant*, not quite *Duff's device*:

```
switch (NumberOfLegs)
{
    case 6:
        SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg6Details());
        goto case 5;
    case 5:
        SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg5Details());
        goto case 4;
    case 4:
        SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg4Details());
        goto case 3;
    case 3:
        SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg3Details());
        goto case 2;
    case 2:
        SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg2Details());
        goto case 1;
    case 1:
        SaveDataALC.SaveFlight(InsertLeg1Details());
        break;
}
```

Comment: Fallthrough in C# need to be written differently compared to C/C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174155/switch-statement-fallthrough-in-c

Comment: (The main idea of making this one-idea "review" community wiki was to enable *every contributor* to edit it. (You will have to decide whether to touch the reopen&close queues RSN.))

Comment: (`continue` might have read more fluently in place of "the `goto <switch label>;`"s - and would have exacted a casuistic definition.)

Comment: I'm guessing that the order of execution is likely to be significant here - but who knows, when we've been shown just a single function out of context?